# PHP get json data with json_decode

Tags: php, json, knockout.js

I'm new to PHP and try to echo out some data from json, but I got stucked in this.

It shows non of the data, but the data is there. The `var_dump()` shows it to me.

Probably I don't use the array correctly, but I can't find what's wrong. I've this code,

I request some data which I gathered with `knockout.js`

Knockout gives me a json (as show below)

```
$json = $_REQUEST[seats];

echo 'requested data raw '. "<br>".$json;
$data = json_decode($json, true);

echo "<br>".'var_dump '. "<br>";
var_dump($data);

foreach ($data  as $optie ) {
    echo "name = " . $optie->name . "<br>";
    echo "optie  = " . $optie->optieName . "<br>";
    echo "prijs    = " . $optie->prijs . "<br>";
}
```

This is my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Naam 1",
        "optie": {
            "optieName": "Make_up",
            "prijs": 9.95
        },
        "PrijsFormated": "Euro: 9.95"
    },
    {
        "name": "Naam 2",
        "optie": {
            "optieName": "Handverzorging",
            "prijs": 12.95
        },
        "PrijsFormated": "Euro: 12.95"
    }
]
```

Comment: you're already use `true` flag on your `json_decode()`, the value is now an array, so access it like one, and you have a typo (i guess) `$_REQUEST[seat]` (missing quotations)

Comment: Correction about my first comment: your $data is an array, NOT an object, therefore, access values as `$optie['name']` and so on, not `$optie->name`. Moreover, I'm not understanding, as I said before, how it is working, since `$_REQUEST[seats]` should be `$_REQUEST['seats'];`

Comment: You decoded it as an `array` (*that second param in `json_decode()` where you set it to `true`*), so you have to access it like an array: `$optio['name']`..etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use such loop:

```
foreach ($data  as $optie ) {
    echo "name = " . $optie['name'] . "<br>";
    echo "optie  = " . $optie['optie']['optieName'] . "<br>";
    echo "prijs    = " . $optie['optie']['prijs']. "<br>";
}
```

Because using `json_decode()` with second parameter as `true` you have created associative array - [documentation](http://php.net//manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

If you would like to access data as object, you should use:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

instead of

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

and then you should use the following loop:

```
foreach ($data  as $optie ) {
    echo "name = " . $optie->name . "<br>";
    echo "optie  = " . $optie->optie->optieName . "<br>";
    echo "prijs    = " . $optie->optie->prijs. "<br>";
}
```

Comment: This is what you should be doing OP.